# built-in air database: is there a way to edit database other then executing queries

Tags: flash, air

Is there a way to alter/create tables in built in air database, other then executing respective queries (gui or whatever)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean editing a 'template' db outside of AIR, then any sqlite editor will do the job. My preference is [sqliteman](http://sqliteman.com/) but I haven't checked if it can open encrypted files - my initial guess would be probably not unless you had the ByteArray stored in such a way that it understood, or if the tool has the popular crypto algorithms baked in.

Me personally, I find it much easier to do development in an unencrypted environment and save that for the end once everything has passed validation.